# Show loader and post AJAX onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

I have a settings page with a form. I noticed that people often forget to click the save button, so I decided to send a POST request with `$.ajax()` on `window.onbeforeunload`. I'd also like a loader (from [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)) to show before sending the request and hide when it is completed.

This is what I have:

```
function save(e) {
  var msg = 'Your settings were not saved. Please do not leave yet so we can try saving again';
  $('form').dimmer('show');

  var xhr = $.ajax('settings.php', {type: "POST", 
    data: $('form').serialize(), async: false});

  $('form').dimmer('hide');

  if (xhr.status !== 200){
    $('form').submit(); //will trigger if the user stays
    if (e)
      return e.returnValue = msg;
  }
}

if ('onbeforeunload' in window)
  window.onbeforeunload = save;
else if ('onunload' in window)
  window.onunload = save;
else {
  var button = $('noscript.submitParent').text();
  $('.ui.form.segment').append(button);
}
```

But now, the loader won't show up until the request is done. I suspect this happens because of `async: false`, which is necessary so that the page does not unload.

Any suggestions on how to show the loader before sending the request? Is it possible?
I tried `$(window).trigger('resize')` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005381/3077735) and `$('form .dimmer').height()` (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928389/3077735)), didn't work.

I'm aware of the [localStorage alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902421/3077735), but I'd like not to use it if possible.

I use jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: Sorry, why not save it automatically? Like it's works in Google Docs

Comment: How often? `oninput`? I don't want it to be very often